# Why does ping6 resolve foo.localdomain to ::1?

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, ping

I have a CentOS 7 machine running in VirtualBox. It's connected to a host-only network. The `/etc/hosts` file contains the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
192.168.56.102 prospero.localdomain prospero
192.168.56.105 ariel.localdomain ariel
```

If I ping ariel.localdomain, it pings 192.168.56.105 as expected:

```
# ping -c1 ariel.localdomain
PING ariel.localdomain (192.168.56.105) 56(84) bytes of data
```

If I ping6 ariel.localdomain, it pings ::1, which I did not expect:

```
# ping6 -c1 ariel.localdomain
PING ariel.localdomain(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
```

Additionally, I can ping6 a non-existent foo.localdomain and get the same response, which I definitely did not expect:

```
# ping6 -c1 foo.localdomain
PING foo.localdomain(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
```

Why does ping6 resolve *.localdomain to localhost?

Since there are no DNS servers on the host-only network, queries that rely on DNS time out, e.g.:

- `nslookup`
- `dig`
- `host`

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your `hosts` file, the answer to the question "what is the IPv6 address of ariel.localdomain" is not coming from it but, most probably, from a DNS server which would be configured to answer `::1` to any request of the type `*.localdomain` (BTW, I would not be surprised that `foo.localdomain` would also resolve to `127.0.0.1` in the IPv4 domain).

When using `nslookup` (or `dig`, or `hosts`) in debug mode, you can figure out where the information is coming from. See the first two lines in the (fictitious) example below:

```
$ nslookup -debug -type=AAAA foo.localdomain
Server:     ns1.google.com
Address:    216.239.32.10#53
...
foo.localdomain has AAAA address ::1
```

Finally, note that `localdomain` is usually used for your loopback network (`127/8`) and not for your LAN (`192.168.56/24` in your case). Hosts `xxx.localdomain` are generally expected to be local to your machine (i.e. with an IPv4 address `127.x.x.x`). This is just a convention, though, but that may explain why you would have a DNS answering this way.

Comment: I'm using a host-only network adapter. nslookup, dig, and host connections time out. I'll edit the question to reflect this info.

Comment: @cherdt `strace getent hosts foo.localdomain` may give you some hints on what exactly is answering you.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the `strace` output to [http://termbin.com/zq7u](http://termbin.com/zq7u). I'll take a look and see what I can figure out.

Comment: @cherdt From your strace output, I can only see that it tries unsuccessfully to reach a local DNS server (you must have `127.0.0.1` in your `resolv.conf`). From what follows, I don't understand how it can resolve `foo.localdomain`.