# Why does *.localhost resolve to 127.0.0.1 and ::1?

Tags: arch-linux, dns

I discovered by chance (trying to access a proxied service in a Docker container on a Vagrant box using servicename.docker.localhost from the host) that any hostname ending in ".localhost" resolves to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 on my machine:

```
$ ping -4 -c1 -n foo.localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.147 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.147/0.147/0.147/0.000 ms
$ ping -6 -c1 -n foo.localhost
PING foo.localhost(::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms

--- foo.localhost ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.072/0.072/0.072/0.000 ms
```

However, there is no DNS entry for this:

```
$ nslookup -type=AAAA foo.localhost
Server:     192.168.2.82
Address:    192.168.2.82#53

** server can't find foo.localhost: NXDOMAIN
$ nslookup -type=A foo.localhost
Server:     192.168.2.82
Address:    192.168.2.82#53

** server can't find foo.localhost: NXDOMAIN
```

/etc/hosts doesn't look particularly relevant:

```
127.0.0.1   my-machine-name.my-work-domain  my-machine-name localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

Neither does /etc/resolv.conf:

```
domain my-work-domain
search my-work-domain
nameserver 192.[…]
nameserver 192.[…]
```

Why does *.localhost magically resolve?

This is similar but possibly distinct from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333821/3645).

---

```
$ getent hosts
127.0.0.1       my-machine-name.my-work-domain my-machine-name localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
$ getent hosts foo.localhost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: What does `getent` say?

Comment: Are you using systemd? It has a [last resort resolver](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) that (if none other nameserver resolved it before) resolves localhost to `::1`.

Comment: @Isaac I think you can write that as an answer. From the page you linked to: "systemd-resolved synthesizes DNS resource records (RRs) for the following cases: [...] any hostname ending in ".localhost" or ".localhost.localdomain") are resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1"

Comment: Also just FYI, before `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` there is `/etc/nsswitch.conf` which controls what sources the libc resolver uses, and in what order. `grep '^hosts:' /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the `myhostname` NSS module which defines the hostname and any name ending in .localhost as 127.0.0.1 in ipv4 and ::1 in ipv6.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-myhostname.html

Comment: nss-systemd could theoretically do something similar but not only is Arch Linux not configured like this by default nor is systemd.

Comment: You nailed it - [/etc/nsswitch.conf](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/fab14862029b1f6b4179b4a2e833304a7b26134e/modules/service_discovery_system/files/nsswitch.conf#L10) enables `myhostname`.